# Backporting C# interpolated string operator $

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, c#-6.0

I have some code I want to reuse in older versions of c#

```
List<string> programId = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"}
string.Join(",", Id.Select(x => $"'{x}'"))
```

How would `$` operator be translated to older version of C# ?

Comment: Backport to older .NET? No need, works out of the box.

Comment: @leppie - `$` for string interpolation is new to C# 6.0.

Comment: @Tim: Even if you select .NET 2 in VS2015 and use it, the C# 6 compiler will compile compatible code.

Comment: @leppie - Really?  So it's truly syntatic sugar then.

Comment: @Tim: Mostly, for newer .NET, `IFormattable` could come into play (but I have not really seen this in practice) Edit: Oops, it could be some other interface I dont recall now :D

Comment: @leppie wasn't it `IFormatProvider`? I'm not sure, either way, it really is syntatic sugar. The compiler converts it to a string.Format call before compiling it to IL code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$"'{x}'"
```

translates to

```
string.Format("'{0}'", x)
```

in older versions of C#.

In fact, the String Interpolation version is just compiler syntactic sugar.  If you decompile the resulting assembly, you'll find out it all resolves to `string.Format` calls.

Comment: I do think, ReSharper can forward and backward translate between `$` interpolation and `string.Format`.

Comment: It can.  At my current job we use CSScript, which doesn't do string interpolation, so I'm always ignoring Resharper's helpful suggestions to convert to string interpolation.

Comment: I do _love_ [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/) and use it all the time for all my setup build and deploy scripts! Oleg does an awesome work and support.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I dont know much about CSScript, but you could always set the c# language level to a lower one, so It doesnt suggest interpolation

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
string.Join(",", Id.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)))
```